# MVC ICollection<IFormFile> ValidationState always set to Skipped

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As part of an **ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0** project, I have a ViewModel with an `ICollection<>` property. I need to validate that this collection contains one or more items. My custom validation attribute doesn't get executed.

In my instance it holds multiple file attachments from a `multipart/form-data` form.

I have decorated the property in the ViewModel with a custom validation attribute:

```cs
[RequiredCollection]
public ICollection<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
```

Below is the custom attribute class. It simply checks the collection is not null and has greater than zero elements:

```cs
public class RequiredCollectionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected const string DefaultErrorMessageFormatString = "You must provide at least one.";

    public RequiredCollectionAttribute() : base(DefaultErrorMessageFormatString) { }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var collection = (ICollection) value;

        return collection == null || collection.Count > 0
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
    }
}
```

And finally, in the controller I am ensuring the ViewModel in the `POST` request is valid, which *should* trigger the validation:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method(MethodViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(viewModel);
    ...
}
```

If I break at the `ModelState.IsValid` call, the contents of `ModelState.Values` for the `Attachments` property is:

[image: Visual Studio Locals Window]

## Question

- **Why doesn't my breakpoint within the `RequiredCollectionAttribute.IsValid()` method ever get hit?**
- **Why does the `ValidationState` get set to `Skipped` for the `Attachments` property?**

--

#### *Edit 1*:

MethodViewModel definition, as requested:

```
public class MethodViewModel
{
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Attachments")]
    [RequiredCollection(ErrorMessage = "You must attached at least one file.")]
    public ICollection<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

--

#### *Edit 2*:

Below is the trimmed value of `actionContext.ModelState` (exported in JSON), as requested. This is the state when a breakpoint is hit on entry to a global action filter, `OnActionExecuting()`:

```
{
    "Count": 19,
    "ErrorCount": 0,
    "HasReachedMaxErrors": false,
    "IsReadOnly": false,
    "IsValid": true,
    "Keys": 
    [
        "Attachments"
    ], 
    "MaxAllowedErrors": 200,
    "ValidationState": Valid,
    "Values": 
    [
        {
            "AttemptedValue": null,
            {
            }, 
            "RawValue": null,
            "ValidationState": Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Skipped
        }
    ], 
    {
        [
            "Key": "Attachments",
            {
                "AttemptedValue": null,
                "RawValue": null,
                "ValidationState": Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Skipped
            }, 
            "key": "Attachments",
            {
                "AttemptedValue": null,
                "RawValue": null,
                "ValidationState": Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Skipped
            } 
        ]
    } 
}
```

--

#### *Edit 3*:

The view's razor syntax to render the `Attachments` input field.

```
<form role="form" asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="Method" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Attachments" class="control-label col-xs-3 col-sm-2"></label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Attachments" class="form-control" multiple required>
            <span asp-validation-for="Attachments" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think this validation will be triggered for this ICollection property. Instead apply an attribute at class level and check the collection from there.

Comment: @E-Bat Please can you explain what you mean by "apply an attribute at class level"?

Comment: How are you materializing the collection, I mean, what implementation of ICollection are you using at runtime?

Comment: @E-Bat The collection is initialised 'behind-the-scenes' by the de-serialisation of the `POST` data from the view. Looking at my locals window, it takes the form of a `System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.AspNet.Http.IFormFile>`.

Comment: @E-Bat `type="file"` gets added automatically by the ASP.NET tag helper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It looks like MVC is suppressing further validation if the `IFormFile` or a collection of `IFormFile` is found to be not null.**

If you take a look at the `FormFileModelBinder.cs` code, [you can see the issue right here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/373361675c74af3376bcfa59cb881519e79081c5/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/FormFileModelBinder.cs#L70). It is suppressing validation if the binder is able to get a non-null result from the if/elseif/else clause above.

In a test, I made a view model with code like this:

```
[ThisAttriuteAlwaysReturnsAValidationError]
public IFormFile Attachment { get;set; }
```

When I actually upload a file to this example, the always-erroring attribute above it never gets called.

Since this is coming from MVC itself, I think your best bet for this is to implement the `IValidateableObject` interface.

```
public class YourViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public ICollection<IFormFile> Attachments { get;set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var numAttachments = Attachments?.Count() ?? 0;
        if (numAttachments == 0)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                "You must attached at least one file.",
                new string[] { nameof(Attachments) });
        }
    }
}
```

This method will still be called as it is not associated with any individual property, and thus isn't suppressed by MVC like your attribute is.

If you've got to do this in more than one place, you could create an extension method to help.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) =>
        collection == null || !collection.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
```

### Update

This has been [filed as a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4329) and should be fixed in 1.0.0 RTM.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and for raising the bug report. Great that it's been acknowledged by the ASPNET team as a valid issue. Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer** (just for code sharing purpses)

try this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequiredCollectionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "You must provide at least one.";
        var collection = value as ICollection;

        return collection != null || collection.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

also, try to add a filter.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new RequestValidationFilter());
```

and write the filter itself:

```
public class RequestValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var errors = actionContext.ModelState
                                      .Values
                                      .SelectMany(m => m.Errors
                                                        .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);

            actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = string.Join("\n", errors);
        }
    }
}
```

just for us to check if a breakpoint is triggered inside the filter.

Comment: Tried overriding the method signature you suggested above but this doesn't resolve it. The `ValidationState` is still set to `Skipped` for `viewModel.Attachments`.

Comment: can you provide the declaration of MethodViewModel  please?\

Comment: Added definition to question

Comment: i edited an error i had here checking if collection is null instead of different from null. have you noticed it?
On my server it's working, so there is probably smth we're missing.
in the code i gave you, is a break point on ErrorMessage line being triggered?

Comment: You're right, that was a typo, should be `!= null`. I have a breakpoint on entry to the `IsValid` method and it never breaks.

Comment: @ChrisPickford see editted answer. also, if you may, screen shot the value of actionContext.ModelState

Comment: Added value of `actionContext.ModelState` to question when the breakpoint gets hit inside the global action filter.