# Upload file with .net core MVC using ajax and pass as model

Tags: c#, ajax, file, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm trying to upload image using .net core with mvc ajax

**here is my code**

```
<form asp-action="AddImages" asp-controller="UserAdmin"
                      data-ajax-begin="onBeginSubmit" data-ajax-complete="onComplete"
                      data-ajax-failure="onFailed" data-ajax-success="onSuccessSubmit"
                      data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input id="file-input-1" name="Image" type="file" class="uploadimg" data-id="1" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" />

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Here is my Model**

```
public class ImageModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Image of Product")]
        public List<IFormFile> Image { get; set; }
    }
```

**And my method**

```
  [HttpPost]
        public bool AddImages(ImageModel Image)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

but **Image** is null and model always return false

Comment: In you model you have List of IFormFile and you're passing a single value of IFormFile. Change the datatype of Image from List<IFormFile> to IFormFile or the second options to change the name of the input in the html from Image to Image[0].

Comment: It seems that there is no problem with your code. There should be another things which you didn't share with us.

Comment: i have tried without ajax its working "<form asp-action="AddImages" asp-controller="UserAdmin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">"

Comment: what could be the problem with ajax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC ICollection<IFormFile> ValidationState always set to Skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989885/mvc-icollectioniformfile-validationstate-always-set-to-skipped)

Comment: Refer an article which will help you in details Link :- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1203408/Upload-Download-Files-in-ASP-NET-Core

Comment: I have this problem too, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @zola25 no i didn't find anything

Answer (score 3):

I've just come up against this problem myself, and it seems the only way around it is to use "traditional" ajax to post the form back to the controller.  My method was as follows:-

Replace the Submit button with a normal button that calls the Ajax:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" onclick="javascript:submitForm()" />
```

Then use Ajax to gather the form data and post it back to the controller action:

```
 function submitForm() {
    var formdata = new FormData($('#yourFormId').get(0));
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //rendering success
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //rendering errors
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps somebody out.  Shame the new "data-ajax" form tags don't seem to be able to handle posting files back.